# python pandas read_csv length is > rows in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When i did `file = pd.read_csv("x.csv")`, it does read the csv into a dataframe and doing `head()` it looks alright with the correct columns shown.

As my csv has 1M + rows, i expect to see 1M + when i do `len(file)`, but i saw 19M+. What could be the problem? Using my friend's computer and doing the same thing for a test csv file gives the right number of rows after doing len(file).

The file contains weird special characters  like chinese characters that are probably shown as ?? in the csv.

Thus, i'm quite sure it isn't because of the function used - is it more likely the difference between python 2 and 3, delimiter used (default ,) or dirty data such as missing rows, or other reasons?

E.g csv containing

```
col1 col2 col3 col4

a       112      111       q??p
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without your data that others can use to try and reproduce

Comment: python 2.7 or python 3?

Comment: Python 3 i suppose! It's able to run, so it's probably not a syntax issue.
It could be dirty data - but as we know csv has limited rows up to 1M+

Comment: Maybe there is comma or newline characters in the CSV file that are creating problems with the dataframe creation in pandas

Comment: @SreeramTP Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding commas in a column value in a test csv - it gives the same length value as without adding. That's the delimiter so newline wouldn't matter?

Comment: Please share the screenshot of head and temp code. That will give a brief idea.